# Error using foreach and Promisse.all in node

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am stuck with this code:

```
  await Promise.all(auxusers.forEach(async (element: any) => {

       const userPopulated: any = new Object();
        userPopulated.hours = await this.hoursRepository.find({ where: { userId : { like: element.id}}});
        userPopulated.generalinfo = element;
        usersArray.push(userPopulated);
      }
        
));
return usersArray
```

It´s return me: Promise.all for each, error: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

Any idea? I am really don´t know what more can I trie

Thanks in advance.

Best,

Comment: Read this: https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/ . Foreach cannot be used in 
 async/await promises. Also if you want promise.all push all promises in array and then run it, not inside loop. From here: https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `foreach` does not return an array.
I would suggest to use `map` instead.

Check the code below:

```js
const users = [1,2,3,4,5];

Promise.all(
  users.map(async (element) => {
    const userPopulated = {};
    userPopulated.hours = Promise.resolve(element);
    userPopulated.generalinfo = element;
    return element;
  })
 ).then((a) => console.log(a))
```